# Configurable products..... Am I missing something?

Tags: configurable-product

I am quite a new user to Magento. Currently using 1.9.2.1 with 3rd party theme.

I am setting up configurable products. I see on the shop side any combination not available still shows up as a drop down option but is "greyed out" so it cant be selected. Is this a new thing?

I am sure an older version I used a while back any combination not available just didnt show on the drop downs. Also the Youtube vids I have watched about setting up configurables shows it so when something is not an available option it doesnt show.

It has been driving me mad as I am sure it used to do this. Either Magento has changed standard behaviour or I have changed an option setting somewhere and cant find how to change it back!

I even installed a default store on a spare domain just to check how it works "out the box"

Can anyone shed some light on this please!! Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want the Not available to NOT show?

Comment: Yes. At the moment all configurable "simple" options show the drop downs (3 drop down menus on the configurable)

Any combination not available just "greys out" and wont allow it to be selected.

I would like it so any combination not available doesnt show. I would still like out of stock options to show so they can be ordered as pre orders.

Comment: Like the way it works in this video https://youtu.be/-J06JAyf3gs?t=15m46s

I dont understand why my install is not working the same way as the Youtube vid. Did something change in a recent update?

Comment: Anyone?? I`m a bit stuck on this atm.

Answer (score 1):

This change happened with the Swatch Module addition as well as the RWD theme. If you switch back to the Magento default package and the default theme you will see that you will get a different look and feel for your configurable products.

If you go to system->config->configurable swatches you will notice there are no setting for stock or out-of-stock display variations.

[image]

If you look at the default version of Magento with the Madison Island theme installed you will notice that the stock item is set to NOT DISPLAY out of stock products

[image]

The point is that this is a theming issue that you will have to do in your theme. You can't set this on the backend of Magento (Which is what I think you are asking.) I am attaching a picture of the default data with the default theme as well.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for taking the time to answer. This explains why it changed as I first used an older version of Magento before colour swatches were introduced.


The next question, do you know a way to make configurable products act like the old way with non available options not showing? I am not using swatches, just the basic drop downs. I am quite happy to buy a module if someone can point me in the right direction of what would work best,