# Configurable Product problem in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, magento-community

I created Configurable Product based on size and gender it was perfectly work, to explain more i have shoes as my product with size 39,42,43,44 with male and female but i have only 39 for female the it mean i have the shoes with size 39 just for female, the rest is belong to male 42,43,44 when i clicked on female i have a opportunity to choose 42,43,44 but actually i don't have this size for female, and when i want to checkout this message with come

> Critical! Please specify the product's option(s).
>   my point is when somebody choose female directly the size of 42,43,44 will be unclickable, after that the customer know that we don't have this product size for female.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: I would use jQuery to show hide based upon condition.  Although I don't have a previous example of something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation of this behaviour (if you are using Magento 1.9.1 or higher) - 
[Configurable products..... Am I missing something?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89256/configurable-products-am-i-missing-something)